# Laravel creating data using ckeditor returns empty fields

Tags: php, laravel, ckeditor

So i have an Table called 'FAQ' in here I have (question, answer, folder_id).
for the question and answer i want to use CKeditor5. i can see the CKeditor clearly and the fonts etc are useable. but when i want to post the data to my controller I get this message back:
[image]

even though i filled these fields in, any idea how to resolve this error?

Create.blade

```
 <form method="post" action="{{ route('admin.faq.store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf
        <div name="question">
            <label for="question">{{('question')}}</label>
            <div class="form-group" id="editorClassic" >
                <input type="text" class="form-control" >
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div>
            <label for="answer">{{('answer')}}</label>
            <div class="form-group" id="editor">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="answer" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="folder_id">{{('folder')}}</label>
            <select name="faqsfolder_id">
                @foreach($faqsfolder as $faqsfolder)
                <option value="{{$faqsfolder->id}}">{{$faqsfolder->name}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>

        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add FAQ</button>
    </form>
```

store function (not finished i know)

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'question' => 'required',
            'answer' => 'required',
            'faqsfolder_id' => [
                'required', 'exists:folder,id'
            ],
        ]);
```

Comment: Can you verify what data is in your request?

Comment: i dont think i can, i tried to put a DD under the $request->validate, but it still returns "The question field is required" etc.

Comment: You should be able to see in the webbrowser what you are sending to the server. If you use chrome devtools->network->all->select request->(on right side) select payload

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/LP8C3n9

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/e60F0NW

Comment: Thanks for verifying! So what we see is that you are indeed not sending the required variables to laravel. I think you need to provide a `name` attribute with the name `question`, where you currently have `<input type="text" class="form-control" >`

Comment: i addded a name to the input, but this does not solve it for some weird reason

Comment: Maybe because you still have `name` on the `div` ?

Comment: i do not have the name in the div anymore

Comment: Can you verify your html in the browser contains your changes ?

Comment: And to verify, can you see the question in the payload in devtools ?

Comment: i can see the question in the payload, and now i noticed that i do not type in the input for some reason https://imgur.com/a/8GBvyoU whenever i hover over the cirkeled part. the part where i type highlights, but whenever i hover over the input. nothing highlights

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249215/discussion-between-techno-and-delano-van-londen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `name` attribute for your input `<input type="text" class="form-control" >`

If you change it into `<input type="text" class="form-control" name="question">` then your variable should be sent to the server :D